# Breaking out of if statement

Tags: c++

I am writing a program in which I use an if statement to check some condition; if true I increment a counter. The problem is that as soon as the statement is true the variable either gets incremented endlessly or by random number.

I have been trying to use some clause to break out of this statement if condition meet but with no luck

my code:

```
if(res_vect_angle >=60 && res_vect_angle <=100 && left_mag_b >100)
{

  //line(drawing, *iter_s, *(iter_s -1),  Scalar( 255, 255, 255 ), 2,8 );
  left_hook_count++;
  cout<<"Left Hook:..........................!!! "<<left_hook_count<<endl;

  if(left_hook_count++ == true)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

The whole chunk of code associated with the issue:

```
float M1, M2;
float A1, A2;
double left_mag_a, left_mag_b;
double res_vect_angle;

int i = 0;

    for(vector<Point>::iterator iter_lh = Leftarm.begin(); iter_lh != Leftarm.end(); ++iter_lh)     
    {       
        if(iter_lh->y <=240 && iter_lh->y >=60 && iter_lh->x >=340 && iter_lh->x <=680)
        {
            left_detect.push_back(*iter_lh);

            if(i % 4 == 0)
            {
                if(left_detect.size()>4)
                    {
                        for(vector<Point>::iterator iter_s = left_detect.begin()+3; iter_s != left_detect.end(); ++iter_s, i++)
                        {
                            //Resultant Magnetude
                            M1 = pow((double) iter_s->x + (iter_s -2)->x,2);
                            M2 = pow((double) iter_s->y + (iter_s -2)->y,2);

                            left_mag_a = (M1 + M2);

                            left_mag_b = sqrt(left_mag_a);

                            //Resultant Angle
                            A1 = abs(iter_s->x - (iter_s -2)->x);
                            A2 = abs(iter_s->y - (iter_s -2)->y);

                            res_vect_angle = abs(atan2(A1,A2) * 180 /PI);
                            //cout<<"LEFT HOOK ANGLE IS: "<<res_vect_angle<<endl;                           




                            if(res_vect_angle >=60 && res_vect_angle <=100 && left_mag_b >100)
                            {

                                //line(drawing, *iter_s, *(iter_s -1),  Scalar( 255, 255, 255 ), 2,8 );
                                left_hook_count++;
                                cout<<"Left Hook:..........................!!! "<<left_hook_count<<endl;

                                if(left_hook_count++ == true)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }




                        }

                    }
            }
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps guys ps. `left_hook_count++;` is a int variable declared on top of my main().

Comment: where is `left_hook_count`  initialized ?

Comment: `endlessly` ? do you have a loop somewhere ? can you post that code too ?

Comment: What is `left_hook_count`'s type? If it is not a boolean type, comparing it to `true` checks whether it's equal to 1, not whether it's unequal to 0. So if its value is 2, there is nothing to break out of the loop.

Comment: Whoah, what's going on here? You're comparing `left_hook_count` against `true` and then incrementing it? You do realize that any non-zero value in C++ evaluates to `true`? I would compare it against an absolute value, such as 1 or 5 or even `! == 0` at least for clarity's sake if nothing else.

Comment: There is seldom any need to compare booleans: you will get another boolean! Do not say `x == true`, say just `x`; do not say `x == false`, say just `!x`. The other forms, `x != true` or `x != false`, are left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: ok so instead of breaking out of the if statement perhaps i should break out of the loop....? and if so how so that it works with my code. REgards

Comment: Might I also suggest the beauty of vector math over the comparing angles and magnitudes for stuff?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is probably to invert the test, and make all the rest of the outer `if` conditional:

```
if (whatever) {
    // do some stuff
    if (left_hook_count != true) { // or whatever the test should really be
        // do some more stuff
    }
}
```

You could get the program flow you want using `goto` with a label after the outer `if`, but [you don't want to](http://xkcd.com/292/).

On the other hand, it sounds like perhaps this is in a loop, and you don't want to enter the `if` block at all if the counter has been incremented? In that case you want:

```
if (left_hook_count == 0 && whatever) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: @ALOToverflow: Thanks, that's just what I was searching for.

Comment: that argument against `goto` was just poor ;-)

Comment: @Walter: Indeed, that's a fairly unlikely consequence of using it. The best argument for not using it is that if you don't use it, you won't need to argue about why you used it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just negate the condition, instead of trying to *break out* of the if:

```
if(...) {
   if(!left_hook_count++) {
      // Do what you need to do
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could provide more details so that we can figure out whats happening.

You might not have initialized it? 
and checking again

```
if(left_hook_count++ == true)
```

it will increment it again unneccessariy and for for first count (0 : it wont happen)

i guess you 're using some recursive function. so check for Break condition (all test cases too).

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare `left_hook_count++` to `true`. In this context, `true` is equal to 1, and once `left_hook_count` exceeds 1, this test will fail and the code will never hit the `break`.

And you don't break out of an if statement. You break out of a loop; a `break` in an `if` statement inside the loop is one way of doing this.

Comment: thanks for your replay.....How would you implement your solution to my code....? Regards

Comment: @Tomazi - I have no idea what your actual loop termination condition is, and I have no intention of wading through all that code to try to figure it out. It's obvious that the current test doesn't make sense. Beyond that, you have to state clearly what conditions should terminate the loop, and then write code that does that.

Answer (score 0):

my new answer:

```
:mylabel if (some_condition)
{
  //code
  if (some_condition) {break mylabel;}
  //code
}
```

my old answer: Replace the if statement with a while statement containing a unconditional break at the end.
(old answer was before I learned of attaching labels to statement blocks.)

In your case:

```
while(res_vect_angle >=60 && res_vect_angle <=100 && left_mag_b >100)
{

    //line(drawing, *iter_s, *(iter_s -1),  Scalar( 255, 255, 255 ), 2,8 );
    left_hook_count++;
    cout<<"Left Hook:..........................!!! "<<left_hook_count<<endl;

    if(left_hook_count++ == true)
    {
        break;
    }
    break; //this unconditional break makes the while loop act as an if statement
}
```

However if you don't have code after the conditional break what's the point of having it? I'm assuming you've omitted that code? The way you wrote it it would simply break out of the inner for loop.